# How to omit certain values while generating XML from SQL (MS SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

We are generating XML out of our MS SQL Server, and we want to omit 0 values for one generated tag to be not generated in XML report.

Where condition doesn`t help, as then complete tag structure is ommited, not only one value.

```
SELECT                                     
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), [BONUS_AMOUNT]) AS [06_BONUS_AMOUNT]     ,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), [MAXIMUM_AMOUNT]) AS [07_MAXIMUM_AMOUNT]
FROM #xmldatarider rid
```

How to generate XML tag for certain column, only when value is not equal to Zero, please?

so Lets`say, this row would be ommited:

```
<tns:attributeCurrency xmlns:tns="BigDataFeed" idx="4" col="4" name="BONUS_AMOUNT" value="0" currency="EUR" />
```

But it would be kept in case there is other value than 0.

Really simplified version:
I have a table, out of which I create XML file:
 code:
 `SELECT PolicyKey, PremiumDebtAmount, DebtKey FROM [DWH].[tgt].[Debt] where PolicyKey IN (4,5) for xml PATH('Debt'), elements go`

Result is 2 XML parent tags, both with 3 values:

`<Debt> <PolicyKey>4</PolicyKey> <PremiumDebtAmount>7.47</PremiumDebtAmount> <DebtKey>241547</DebtKey> </Debt> <Debt> <PolicyKey>5</PolicyKey> <PremiumDebtAmount>5.28</PremiumDebtAmount> <DebtKey>241548</DebtKey> </Debt>`

I want not to show the tag PremiumDebtAmount, when it`s 5.28.

I can`t use where condition, because all tags from parent are then ommited.

Code:

```
SELECT PolicyKey, PremiumDebtAmount, DebtKey 
FROM [DWH].[tgt].[Debt] 
where PolicyKey IN (4,5) and PremiumDebtAmount<>5.28 
for xml PATH('Debt'), elements
```

Result:

```
<Debt> 
    <PolicyKey>4</PolicyKey> 
    <PremiumDebtAmount>7.47</PremiumDebtAmount> 
    <DebtKey>241547</DebtKey> 
</Debt>
```

What I do need to see is:

```
<Debt> 
    <PolicyKey>4</PolicyKey> 
    <PremiumDebtAmount>7.47</PremiumDebtAmount> 
    <DebtKey>241547</DebtKey> 
</Debt> 
<Debt> 
    <PolicyKey>5</PolicyKey> 
    <DebtKey>241548</DebtKey> 
</Debt>
```

And my question is how :)

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using a `WHERE` clause ? What do you use to generate XML anyway? Your question doesn't contain the  `FOR XML` clause.

Comment: Nesting typed XML is one option: `DECLARE @OmittedValue INT = 3; SELECT a = 1, (SELECT @OmittedValue OmittedValue WHERE @OmittedValue <> 0 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) FOR XML PATH('')` (try it with `@OmittedValue = 0`). Whether and how to apply that to your case would need more detail on your actual query -- the snippet you have there is a long way from producing the desired output.

Comment: You don't need to to convert non string data types to a `(n)varchar` when creating XML either, the statement will handle all of that.

Comment: yes Panagiotis, I tried where, as I write in original text, it removes all values within XML tree :) Therefore I would need some other solution, which would keep the rest of values. The code has 1300 lines, I put only a part where I would need an update due to requirement.

Comment: Jeroen why INT=3 and SELECT a=1 please?
What does it mean?

Comment: Really simplified version: I have a table, out of which I create XML file:
code: SELECT 

PolicyKey,
PremiumDebtAmount,
DebtKey
  FROM [DWH].[tgt].[Debt]
  where PolicyKey IN (4,5)  
  for xml PATH('Debt'), elements
  go
Result is 2 XML parent tags with 3 values:
<Debt>
  <PolicyKey>4</PolicyKey>
  <PremiumDebtAmount>7.47</PremiumDebtAmount>
  <DebtKey>241547</DebtKey>
</Debt>
<Debt>
  <PolicyKey>5</PolicyKey>
  <PremiumDebtAmount>5.28</PremiumDebtAmount>
  <DebtKey>241548</DebtKey>
</Debt>

I want not to show the tag PremiumDebtAmount, when it`s 5.28.

Comment: I can`t use where condition, because all tags from parent are ommited. Code:
SELECT PolicyKey, PremiumDebtAmount, DebtKey  FROM [DWH].[tgt].[Debt]
  where PolicyKey IN (4,5)  
  and PremiumDebtAmount<>5.28
  for xml PATH('Debt'), elements  go

Result: <Debt>
  <PolicyKey>4</PolicyKey>
  <PremiumDebtAmount>7.47</PremiumDebtAmount>
  <DebtKey>241547</DebtKey>
</Debt>What I do need to see is:
<Debt>
  <PolicyKey>4</PolicyKey>
  <PremiumDebtAmount>7.47</PremiumDebtAmount>
  <DebtKey>241547</DebtKey>
</Debt>
<Debt>
  <PolicyKey>5</PolicyKey>  
  <DebtKey>241548</DebtKey>
</Debt>

Comment: As you can see, comments are an absolutely terrible way of supplying more details -- nobody can read that. Edit your original question to include these details.

Comment: ok :) edited main question

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to a slightly simplified version of your problem, showing the use of nested typed XML:

```sql
DECLARE @Debt TABLE (
    PolicyKey NVARCHAR(100),
    PremiumDebtAmount DECIMAL(5, 2),
    DebtKey INT
)
INSERT @Debt VALUES (4, 7.47, 241547), (5, 5.28, 241548)

SELECT 
    PolicyKey, 
    (
        SELECT PremiumDebtAmount 
        WHERE PremiumDebtAmount <> 5.28
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ),
    DebtKey
FROM @Debt
FOR XML PATH('Debt')
```

Result:

```
<Debt>
    <PolicyKey>4</PolicyKey>
    <PremiumDebtAmount>7.47</PremiumDebtAmount>
    <DebtKey>241547</DebtKey>
</Debt>
<Debt>
    <PolicyKey>5</PolicyKey>
    <DebtKey>241548</DebtKey>
</Debt>
```

Comment: hm I receive an error message: Column name 'xx' contains an invalid XML identifier as required by FOR XML; '0'(0x0030) is the first character at fault.

query is: ,(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), [Bonusová poistná suma]) AS [06_Bonusová_poistná suma] WHERE [Bonusová poistná suma] <> 0 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)

by error message I found information : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731465/sql-server-contains-an-invalid-xml-identifier-as-required-by-for-xml

but I think there are no unnecessary zeros, so I am not sure why it doesn`t work

Comment: An XML name can contain `0` but can't start with `0`; it can only use `_` and letters. If you've attempted to do something like `SELECT 0 AS [06_BONUS_AMOUNT] FOR XML PATH('')` (directly or indirectly) you get this error. Fixing that means changing either the name or your XML structure.

Comment: but strange that for the rest of query it`s ok, only another inner select is causing a problem:
  ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), [Poistná suma]) AS [05_Poistná suma]
                    ,(SELECT [Bonusová_poistná_suma] AS [Bonusová_poistná_suma] WHERE [Bonusová_poistná_suma] <> 0 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
                    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), [Poistné]) AS [07_Poistné]

Comment: The only reason it would be "OK" for the rest of the query is if the XML isn't actually generated at that level, but higher up the chain. You are free to have columns called `05_...` inside a query, but not if those have to end up as XML elements -- so I suspect you're putting the `FOR XML PATH('')` somewhere too early. Without a complete query and a way to reproduce this, it's not possible to tell.

Comment: Jeroen thanks. may I send you personal message with the query? the code is too long to be posted here

Comment: Hi Jeroen, I tried everything but I am not able to solve the problem :(
Could you please help?